# Trying to learn the KVM and VCPUs structs

Tags: qemu, kvm

Please bear with me as I'm trying to learn the particulars of the KVM and VCPUs structs in hopes to write some code to utilize them.  I've been looking through the code to try and figure things out but I'm still a little unclear.  Regarding the KVM struct, when a VM is created is there a KVM struct for that KVM?  So is there a 1:1 relationship there?  Looking through the struct and code that looks to be the case to me.  Regarding the VPCU struct, I noticed there is a pointer to the KVM struct.  Is this just a recursive pointer back to the KVM struct that the VCPU struct is in?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

There is one kvm struct per virtual machine. This struct contains an array called vcpus, the elements of which are pointers to the vcpus associated with the 'machine'.

If you wanted to know that, you may also be interested in the fact that the vm_list member of the kvm struct can be used to iterate through all of the kvm-based virtual machines on the host.